# How to team player with the first player they see?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a 1.14 minecraft minigame, and one aspect is when two players not on a team walk up to each other, they are put on the same team. I am wondering how to do this.I have included all 16 team colo(u)rs, and the team names are:

dark_red, green, dark_green, yellow, black, dark_blue, dark_purple, gold, red, aqua, gray, light_purple, blue, white, dark_aqua, dark_gray

Comment: Use raycasting to add a tag to a player the ray intersects. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9XWkA6bF36c Is a good resource for how to do it, and the basic command still works in 1.14.

Comment: @Nik3141 i'm not sure how that would work?

Comment: Do you need to do it if there are two players *next* to each other or *looking* at each other? I'll write an answer for being next to each other and then if you need looking I'll write another.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question was asked before, but I can't find it. If someone has a link, please post it in a comment (or contact me otherwise if you can't).

Answer (score 1):

To team players who are within five blocks of one another who don't currently have a team:

In a repeating command block:

`execute as @a[team=] at @s if @a[team=,distance=1..5,limit=1] run execute as @a[distance=..5,limit=2] run team join <team name> @s`

What this does is it executes as a player who has no team at that player if there is a single player within 1 to 5 blocks away who also doesn't have a team. It runs another execute function which executes as both players joining them both to a team. If you want to randomize which team they join try something like this:

Setup a scoreboard to track the current time:
`/scoreboard objectives add time dummy`

In a repeating command block set the scoreboard to the current time:
`execute store result score @a time run time query daytime`

In a number of similar repeating command blocks set a particular team depending on the current time: in this example green is for 1000 to 2000:

`execute as @a[team=] at @s if @a[team=,distance=1..5,limit=1] run execute as @a[distance=..5,limit=2] if score @s time matches 1000..2000 run team join green @s`

You'd need a different command block for each team and time.

Comment: TIL that "`team=`" is a complete selector argument. Interesting.